# Parameter type and number checking in c

Tags: c, function, parameters

I am looking to add a check to make sure the below function is always called with the correct number of parameters and that they are of the correct type. What is the best way to go around this?

e.g.

```
int differance(int *a, int *b)
{
 //Work out difference
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean you pass two arrays, and want to make sure they are both of the same size?

Comment: No I want to ensure that they are both int's and that there were only 2 parameters passed

Comment: your prototype makes the compiler do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler will do that for you.

If you declare a function as taking two argument you can't call it with less or more arguments or you will get an error.

If you try to pass a pointer to something else than an `int` then the compiler will at least warn you, possibly even giving you an error.

Answer (score 3):

To ensure your function calls match your function definitions:

- For functions defined and used in a single source file, declare or define the function before it is used.
- For functions defined and used across multiple source files, declare the function in a header file (name ends with .h) and use #include to include that header file in each source file that defines or uses the function. The #include should be before any definition or use of the function.
- Check your compiler settings and ensure that warnings are turned on for missing function prototypes and for mismatched function prototypes.
- Turn on warnings for dangerous implicit conversions, if your compiler has such warnings.
- Do not declare parameters as “void *” if you can avoid it. Generally, you want to keep type information so the compiler can check it.